# How to make this Active record query work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my DB I have a bunch of listings with different city names. Im trying to keep only those listings in this db that have city name = X and remove all other cities.

Im trying the following Active record Query:

```
@unwanted_cities = Listing.where('city not in (?)', Listing.where('city = ?', "X"));
```

But Im getting this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Unwanted_cities#index

Showing /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/app0521/app/views/unwanted_cities/index.html.erb where     line #31 raised:

PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <> integer
LINE 1: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"  WHERE (city not in (4,1...
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add  explicit type casts.
: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"  WHERE (city not in         (4,10,13,17,18,19,21,23,26,28,29,31,36,39,46,48,49,52,90,97,101,103,105,108,109,111,115,94,5      ,219..............))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@unwanted_cities = Listing.where('city != ?', "X")`

If what I'm reading is correct, you want cities that don't have the name "X". You'll get these cities by executing the above line of code.

If you want to "remove" all of these cities,

`@unwanted_cities.delete_all`

or

`@unwanted_cities.destroy_all`

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the entries where the city is not X.
Thanks, I will try this query. Based on my knowledge of SQL, I thought the symbol for not equal was <>. I tried the query with this symbol but it didnot work. I will try your way now.

Comment: @banditKing Both should work. `Listing.where('city <> ?', "X")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked. I will try with <> again for curiosity sake :)